# Add three integers and report the sign of the sum

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, homework

I am in my first high school programming course; the assignment is:

> Write a program that asks the user to input three integers and outputs
>   a message indicating their sum and whether it is positive, negative,
>   or zero. You should create 2 classes to run this program. One class
>   contains all of the procedures for your program and the other has all
>   of the procedure calls for your program.

I have done exactly what the assignment has asked for me to do; I was wondering if there was anything that I should change to make my code more simple and or more elegant or point out anything that might lead up to errors, since I'm in my first programming course. I really want to start programming with simple elegant code and not messy code, because I feel like it starts good habits for me later on.

````java
import java.util.Scanner;

class ConorsList {
    int total;


    public void add(int number) {
        this.total = this.total + number ;       
    }

    public void status(){
        if(this.total<0) {
                System.out.println("The sum is negative.");
        } else if (this.total>0) {
                System.out.println("The sum is positive");
        } else {
               System.out.println("The sum is equal to zero");
        }
    } 

    public void status(int total){
        if(total<0) {
                System.out.println("The number is negative.");
        } else if (total>0) {
                System.out.println("The number is positive.");
        } else {
               System.out.println("The number is equal to zero.");
        }
    } 
}

public class Class1_2 {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       ConorsList list = new ConorsList();
       Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       int amount = 3;

       for (int n=0; n<amount; n++) {
           int x =fromKeyboard.nextInt();
            list.add(x);
            list.status();
            list.status(x);
       }

   }

}
```
````

Comment: This is actually a rather challenging exercise if you need to take into account the possibility of integer overflow during addition. You're probably not expected to do so, though, if this is a first assignment in a high school course.

Comment: can you explain a little more indepth?

Comment: An `int` can only go as large as 2147683487. If you add 2147383487 to 2147683487, the sum should be positive mathematically, but will be reported as -2 in Java because [the result would be too large to be represented as an `int`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: okay cool, yeah like you said "you're probably not expected to do so" i think the assignment is just to do basic classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Binary operators have spaces before and after them**

In your `main`s `for` loop, you have:

```
int n=0;
```

It is more customary to write `int n = 0;`

**Superfluous new lines**

Given

public class ... {

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       ConorsList list = new ConorsList();
       Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

       int amount = 3;

       for (int n=0; n<amount; n++) {
           int x =fromKeyboard.nextInt();
            list.add(x);
            list.status();
            list.status(x);
       }
       // Why new line here?
   }
   // And here?
}
```

**Superfluous space in the `for` loop**

In the `main`'s `for` loop, you have

```
   for (int n=0; n<amount; n++) {
       int x =fromKeyboard.nextInt();
        list.add(x);
        list.status();
        list.status(x);
   }
```

Should be:

```
    for (int n = 0; n < amount; n++) {
        int x = fromKeyboard.nextInt();
        list.add(x);
        list.status();
        list.status(x);
    }
```

**Bad name**

I suggest you rename `fromKeyboard` to `scanner` here:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

**Superfluous variable**

```
int amount = 3;
```

Having this definition does not buy you much maintainability. I see two options here:

1. Remove it and have `n < 3` in the `for` loop,
2. Declare it `final`.

**Bad class name**

`Class1_2` is a bad name for a class. Since it does nothing but runs you main logic, I suggest you rename it to `Main`, `Demo`, or similar.

**Advice 1**

When you reach a particular level of proficiency in Java, it is advisory to start using **[packages.](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_packages.asp)**

Comment: So i have a lot of unnecessary spaces between lines, and i can make my code less lines by getting rid of those.

if i dont put spaces for the binary ops will that ever lead to an error or is it just it looks better?

Comment: No, it does not lead to errors, but it *may* lead to errors while reading the code. For example: `for(int i=0,j=-1;i>j&&ji+10;i+=2,j-=3)`

Comment: i see now, without the spaces its really hard to read without the spaces,

thanks

Comment: @ConorOepkes No problem. Just remember that readability/maintainability is no less important than correctness.

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language, so there is no need to repeat the type of the variable in it's name. Especially if the type is the only thing in the name. The name "fromKeyboard" was in that sense more descriptive than "scanner". However, as System.in doesn't always come from keyboard, your name can be a bit deceptive. Names should describe what the variables do. E.g. "amount" should be "numOfEntriesToRead".

Comment: Amount should not be replaced with 3 in the for loop. Doing so would trigger a warning for magic numbers in a static code analyzer. The number 3 should be extracted into a constant with a name that describes what it stands for.

Comment: "Class1_2", while it doesn't follow Java naming conventionas, is a lot more descriptuive than "Main" or "Demo". It identifies the class and assignment for which it was written and thus describes it's exact purpose. When the naming convention is followed throughout the class, finding specific code is simple. "Class1Assignment2" would have been better, though, as undserscores do not belong to Java class names. The ConorsList was the actual bad class name as it is neither Conor nor a List. It is an Accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Use shorthand for addition, multiplication, division etc.

E.G instead of `this.total = this.total + number;`

do: `this.total += number;`

You have a lot of code repetition with these two methods. Anytime you copy & paste, you should be asking yourself if you can make the code shorter.

With your overloaded method, it's easy. Just change your no-arg constructor to call the other:

```
public void status(){
    status(this.total);
}
```

You may also want to change the name to `printStatus`. You can further reduce the code, since all of the if statements print a lot of the same characters

E.G:

```
public void status(total){
    String status = "The sum is ";

    if(total<0) {
            status += "negative.";
    } else if (total>0) {
            status += "positive";
    } else {
           status += "equal to zero.";
    }

    System.out.println(status);
}
```